# Vb.net - FileMovement Lock on destination folder

Tags: vb.net

Source code: vb.net

We are using File.Move() method to move the file from source to destination locaion.
But the destination location is being monitored by one tool, whenever we are moving files to the destination location, it will pick up the file and process it. The issue here when we try to move huge volume file like around 5GB file, the tool is immediately picking up the file and try to process it before the move operation is complete and send failure notice to all the users.. After again successfully moving the file completely, it picks up the same and process it sucessfully this time and send successful notice this time.

We can't have control over the tool which is monitoring the destination folder because it is a third party tool. However we want to find out the alternative option to place a lock over the destination foler like ReadWrite access till the move operation completes so that 3rd party will not be able to pick up or try to access that file.

Pls help us.

Comment: did you tried making it readonly?

Comment: Try copying [with streams](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5h0z48dh.aspx) while denying any [sharing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare.aspx).

Comment: Is this all within the same machine, or is it across the network?

Comment: Does this third party tool scan for ALL files, or just specific types?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it works, but you might be able to make the following work with directories as well:

```
FileOpen(1, "c:\file.ext", OpenMode.Binary)    
Lock(1)
'Do something with file here
Unlock(1)
FileClose(1)
```

Reference and example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w804hcwf%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

First, I agree with @hometoast, sometimes tools like this just look for specific file extensions so you can copy in with a different file extension and then rename.

But barring that, download the file to a temp location and then Move the file into the dir getting watched.  A Move does not recopy the file contents but just updates its pointers in the filesystem.  Should be atomic.

Comment: But then, `move` preserves permissions of the file which may be a problem.

Comment: OP did mention any issues with permissions?